# If I delete my own question, can I still see it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

On Stack Overflow, at some point my rep reached a level where I could see deleted questions and answers. They're just grayed out.

On this site, I have very low rep; so I'm sure I can't see deleted questions in general. But what about my *own* question? Can I still see it, if/once I delete it?

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

You should be able to view your own deleted questions.

Comment: ...provided you keep a link to them somewhere (they don't show up in your profile).

Comment: @Mr. CRT: Correct, you would have to keep a link to them.

Comment: Actually, I was just reminded on MSO that this isn't really true... 10K users can see their own deleted questions, just as they can see everyone else's, but low-rep users can't. If they try to navigate back to a question they've deleted it will fail with a 404 error.

Comment: @Mr. CRT: Ah, I can view deleted questions and answers, but I was thinking deleted answers you can view (even with low rep) but not questions.

Comment: Yup, that looks to be the case.